# Boolean-like algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

Suppose one had an algebra that that follows most of the laws of Boolean algebra (associative, commutative, distributive, identity, annihilator, idempotent, double negation, De Morgan) but does not follow the complementation laws   x∧¬x= 0  and x∨¬x=1 ?
It wouldn't be a Boolean algebra, but how would such an algebra be classified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such algebras are in fact called *de Morgan* algebras; they are often classified as a branch of *algebraic logic*.  For more, see [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan_algebra).

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***